# With Swiftmailer, can I replace or remove a message part?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using Swift Mailer to send mail to a fairly large list of email addresses. The message is customized slightly for each recipient. Some placeholders are replaced with unique text.

I assumed it would be more efficient (less garbage collection etc) to reuse one instance of `Swift_Message` multiple times. I just `setTo()`, `setBody()` and send again to the next address.

That works well with a single part body, usually just html. But ... when I want a second part, usually text, I can do `addPart()`, but next time around the loop, that will add another part, and then another part etc ...  The problem doesn't happen with `setBody` because that overwrites the existing body.

Is there a way to overwrite or remove an existing part?

Thanks

Comment: I'd just keep creating a new message in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answers by Hendrik and Alasdair, I suggest looking into using the Decorator plugin.
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#using-the-decorator-plugin

Instead of manipulating the individual message parts, the plugin will replace the desired placeholders of the entire message for each recipient.

For example

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

$replacements = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $replacements[$user['email']] = array(
        '{username}' => $user['username'],
        '{password}' => $user['password']
    );
    $message->addTo($user['email']);
}
$decorator = new \Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
$mailer->registerPlugin($decorator);

$message
    ->setSubject('Important notice for {username}')
    ->setBody(
        "Hello {username}, we have reset your password to {password}\n" .
        "Please log in and change it at your earliest convenience."
    );
$message->addPart('{username} has been reset with the password: {password}', 'text/plain');
//..
$mailer->send($message);
```

---

Additionally in PHP, objects are passed by reference, so you can directly manipulate the individual parts body, or content type.

```
$textPart = \Swift_MimePart::newInstance('Hello World', 'text/plain');
$htmlPart = clone $textPart;
$htmlPart->setContentType('text/html');
$message->setTo('someone@example.com');
$message->attach($htmlPart);
$message->attach($textPart);
//...
$mailer->send($message);

$textPart->setBody('Something Else');
$htmlPart->setBody('Something Else');
$message->setTo('someone.else@example.com');
$mailer->send($message);
```

You can also remove a child part by using

```
$message->detach($textPart);
```

Instead of using detach, which iterates over the parts, looking at how `addPart` and `attach` work, they simply call `setChildren(array_merge($this->getChildren(), array($part)))`

So you can set the children parts manually by defining them, which replaces calling `addPart` or `attach`.

```
$message->setChildren([$htmlPart, $textPart]);
```

For all intents and purposes, if you're removing parts of a Message along with different content (albeit slightly) for another recipient, you're in effect creating a new Message. The programming logic can reflect that by calling `$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()` when the message parts need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Swift Mailer Docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-the-body-content), there is no such method as a `getBody()` really.

I would suggest you to store the actual message *template* containing your placeholders in a variable and use `setBody()` on every iteration to replace the complete body of the message with the parsed template for the new recipient instead of trying to replace a tiny bit of it.

I reckon your code could look something like this:

```
$template = '<h1>Hello {{firstname}}</h1>, ...';
$recipients = [
    ['firstname' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com'],
    ...
];
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject here');

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $body = str_replace('{{firstname}}', $recipient['firstname'], $template);
    $message->setBody($body, 'text/html');

    // continue building the mail object and send it ...
}
```

This way you could indeed re-use the Swift_Message instance for every mail. Although it wouldn't make any difference to PHP if you re-use the instance or create a new one in every loop iteration.

Comment: That works okay for a single part message but the problem is multi-part messages where you need to do $message->addPart() to set the second (usually plain text) part. The "parts" accumulate. I've changed it to create a new instance every time and that works fine. It was probably a micro-optimization for me to be concerned about it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

@tetranz As @Hendrik outlines you can use `$message->getBody()` and `$message->setBody($body)` for the main body part.

You can access the parts (of the multipart `addPart()` you mention) via the same methods of the children. i.e. something similar to:

```
$children = $message->getChildren();
foreach($children as &$child) {
    $c_body = $child->getBody();
    //manipulate as you wish
    $child->setBody($c_body);
}
$message->setChildren($children);
```

This works on Swift v5.0.1